# Why is my custom module is not listed with the drush command pm-projectinfo?

Tags: drush

If you have drush >= 8 you can use `drush pm-projectinfo` to show a report of available projects and their extensions. If you use `drush pm-projectinfo devel` you should see the information about the devel module something like this:

```
 Name             :  Devel (devel)                       
 Type             :  module                              
 Version          :  7.x-1.3                             
 Status           :  1                                   
 Extensions       :  devel                               
                     devel_generate                      
                     devel_node_access                   
 Drush Commands   :  devel-download                      
                     devel-reinstall                     
                     fn-hook                             
                     fn-view                             
                     devel-token                         
 Datestamp        :  1338940281                          
 Path             :  sites/all/modules/development/devel
```

I come from creating a custom module named my_custom_module, but when I use `drush pm-projectinfo my_custom_module` the output is:

```
 [warning] my_custom_module was not found.
```

It's very weird because I know that my module works fine, I use it every day, but the command doesn't work.

How can I solve this? Is it a problem with drush or is it a problem with my custom module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple, you just need to add [project](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202#project) property in your .info file.

In this case:

```
project = "my_custom_module"
```

The Drupal documentation page [Writing module .info files (Drupal 7.x)](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202) says about the project property:

> **project** ***(Discouraged, packaging use only)***
>
> Module maintainers should not use this at all. The packaging script on
>   drupal.org will automatically place a string here to identify what
>   project the module came from. This is primarily for the Update status
>   module, so that Drupal installations can monitor versions of installed
>   packages and notify administrators when new versions are available.

But as this is a custom module I think that I need to put this property in my .info file because if not, `drush pm-projectinfo my_custom_module` will not works.

*Let's see why if you don't use the project property this doesn't works*

Inside the [drush code](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) you can see the implementation of the [drush pm-projectinfo command](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/commands/pm/projectinfo.pm.inc#L20):

```
function drush_pm_projectinfo() {
  // Get specific requests.
  $requests = pm_parse_arguments(func_get_args(), FALSE);
  // Get installed extensions and projects.
  $extensions = drush_get_extensions();
  $projects = drush_get_projects($extensions);
```

If you use:

```
drush ev 'print_r(array_keys((drush_get_extensions())))' | grep my_custom_module
```

You will see something like this:

```
[112] my_custom_module
```

So, we need to test the next step:

```
drush ev 'print_r(array_keys(drush_get_projects(drush_get_extensions())))' | grep my_custom_module
```

Nothing to show

So, if we go inside the [drush_get_projects()](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/e658a9641f498b33c05bb9f66fedcd749e3eeb4f/commands/pm/pm.drush.inc#L658) function we can found the following code in [line 673](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/e658a9641f498b33c05bb9f66fedcd749e3eeb4f/commands/pm/pm.drush.inc#L673):

```
  foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    $extension_name = drush_extension_get_name($extension);
    $extension_path = drush_extension_get_path($extension);
    // Obtain the project name. It is not available in this cases:
    //   1. the extension is part of drupal core.
    //   2. the project was checked out from CVS/git and cvs_deploy/git_deploy
    //      is not installed.
    //   3. it is not a project hosted in drupal.org.
    if (empty($extension->info['project'])) {
```

And in number 3 we have our answer.

Comment: @greg_1_anderson in the case of the custom modules what's the best option to use drush pm-projectinfo?

Comment: Unfortunately, since Greg has not commented nor answered in here, he probably won't get an alert.